# Laravel don't show errors like model path wrong

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I update Laravel to version 6.8 from 5.5 and some errors stop to show, like when you write the namespace wrong or something in model instead show only timeout error, I think this is something related about whoops and ignition
I changed too the errors interface whoops to ignition

Here my composer

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.2.5",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.5",
    "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "^5.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.8",
    "laravel/helpers": "^1.1",
    "laravel/telescope": "^2.1",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
    "rap2hpoutre/fast-excel": "^1.6",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.0",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^9.6"
},
"require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
    "composer/composer": "^1.8",
    "facade/ignition": "^1.6",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
    "spatie/laravel-web-tinker": "^1.5"
},
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/helper.php"
    ],
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
}
```

}

Comment: Did you read the entire release notes & migrating steps? Also, check if your third party packages are compatible with laravel 6.8

Comment: yes, I read all steps, i try download a new project but same error, can be third party packages but all are compatibles with laravel 6.8

Comment: here my composer https://gist.github.com/joefreire/72e66c30fe61b968d2fb070ca3019b5a

Comment: What webserver are you using? Check it lohs, php logs and Laravel logs for errors

Comment: Yes, I check all logs but the error don't show, it's only timeout... I this have something with models errors, I try create a clear install of laravel and same error